# Обновить часть записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите как обновить запросом часть записи в столбце

```
s:15:"STOCK_AND_PRICE";s:1:"N";s:14:"ZERO_PRICE_OLD";s:1:"N";s:18:"ZERO_PRICE_PREMIUM";s:1:"N";s:18:"SHOW_JUST_CATALOGS";s:1:"Y";s:10:"SORT_ORDER";
```

Мне надо чтоб `"ZERO_PRICE_OLD";s:1:"Y";`

Comment: Покажите таблицу нормально (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 2-3 записи), а не одно значение. Покажите, как выглядят входные данные для внесения изменения (какое или какие значения будут передаваться в запрос как параметры). Ну и укажите **точную** версию MySQL.

Comment: @Akina какая разница, если это вывод `serialize` в пхп. Данные надо извлекать, десериализовать, изменить, сериализовать обратно и проапдейтить обычным образом.

Comment: @teran Так-то оно да, но ведь автор зачем-то прилепил теги MySQL и SQL, и проигнорировал тег PHP... вдруг это не от незнания, а по какой-то вменяемой причине?

Comment: @Akina  тут еще вопрос в том, что это не целиком данные сериализации. посокльку это массив, то должно все начинаться с `a:число_элементов:[]` ну или что-то такого. Возможно это какой-то свой способ реализации наподобие serialize, или `o:...` для объекта. Если это обрезано для экономии места, то весьма сомнительный шаг